# How to clean merge commit from commit log?

Tags: git

I have a `master` branch which others will push new staff and a `topic` branch I'm working on, from time to time, I will do `git merge master`, so the commit log of `topic` looks like

```
commit01 topic: add feature01
commit02 Merge master to topic
commit03 topic: add feature02
commit04 Merge master to topic
commit05 topic: add feature03
commit06 topic: update feature04
commit07 Merge master to topic
```

And then I finished my work on `topic` and would like to merge it to `master`, before I merge, I would like to remove these `Merge master to topic` commit logs.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you saying you want to remove the entire merge commits, or just the messages?  Either way, you would have to rewrite the history of the `master` branch in order to do this.  I doubt that is what you would want to do with a production branch.

Comment: Only the message

Comment: Then you may use an interactive rebase and edit the commit message.  But I don't recommend doing this to a published branch.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you sync master branch changes to your branch, you should use

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout <your branch>
git rebase master
```

instead of just `git merge master`

**Note: rebase will change your branch's commit history, maybe you should force push to your branch remote**

when you finish your branch, you firstly rebase master, then `git merge <your branch>`(merge without `--no-ff`) to master.

Then no merge commit will generate.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing the merge commits, you can do a [squash merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---squash) when you bring your changes into master.

This will create a single commit on master that effectively brings in all the changes that would have happened had you done a regular merge. Then, no matter how complicated your topic history was, on master it looks like a single commit.

To do this:

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash topic
git commit
```

There are a few advantages to this method:

1. You don't have to worry about micromanaging your commits. You can keep over-committing tiny spacing changes every few seconds, and it doesn't pollute the history of master.
2. Merges this way result in atomic changes on master. The history of master now only shows pre and post feature, not the individual broken states while you were developing the feature, making it easier to read and navigate the history.
3. Since you can now do clean squash merges in Github, this solution works without any command line refactoring when it comes time to merge.

The main disadvantage of this method is that if multiple people are working on the same feature branch, only one person is able to claim the new squashed commit. This means `git blame` might attribute changes to the wrong person.